What is the spectrum of annihilation and creation operator?
I have been reading up on the spectrum theory and have learned about the point/continuous/residual spectrum. Now I am applying them to various operators in quantum mechanics.
Interestingly, when looking at the annihilation operator, I noticed two seemingly contradictory statements:

Statement 1: The annihilation operator has the coherent states as its eigenstates: $a|\alpha\rangle = \alpha|\alpha\rangle \,\,(\alpha \in \mathbb{C})$, meaning that it has $\mathbb{C}$ as the point spectrum.

Statement 2: The spectrum $\mathbb{C}$ is somehow "continuous".


There must be something wrong in my statement or my contradiction. Either that $\mathbb{C}$ is actually a continuous spectrum, or that the point spectrum can actually be "continuous" in some way, so that "point/continuous spectrum" are kind of a misnomer. Or it could be that the annihilation operator is itself not bounded, so that the whole spectral theory simply does not apply.

Question 1: What am I going wrong here?
Question 2: What is the spectrum of the creation operator?
Question 3: Are there any good materials on the spectral theory in quantum mechanics? Thanks in advance!


Edit: For clarity, I will define the things mentioned.

The Hilbert space of interest is $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, i.e., complex-valued square integrable functions on $\mathbb{R}$, modding the functions whose set of non-zero points has measure zero, the inner product being defined through $\langle g,f \rangle:=\langle f| g \rangle:=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f^*(x)g(x) \mathrm{d}x$. This space is well known to be separable, having a complete countable set of orthonormal basis, for example, the eigenfunctions of a quantum harmonic oscillator: $f_n(x) = N_n \, H_n\left( x \right) e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\,\,(n\in \mathbb{N})$, where $H(x)$ is the Hermite polynomial and $N_n$ is a suitable normalization constant.

The position operator on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is defined through $(Xf)(x) := xf(x)$

The momentum operator on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is defined through $(Pf)(x) := -\mathrm{i}f'(x)$

The annihilation operator on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is defined as $a := X + \mathrm{i}P$. One may also define it through $a f_n := \sqrt{n} f_{n-1}$, which might simplify the analysis by considering the homomorphism from $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ to $l^2(\mathbb{N})$.

The creation operator $a^\dagger$ on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is defined as the adjoint of the annihilation operator.



It may help to write out these operators as well as their domains, as not everyone here is well-versed in QM. I am assuming it is a differential operator and hence it is likely not a bounded operator

Even bounded operators can have a “continuous” point spectrum. Say, the left shift operator $S$ on $\ell^2$ has the open unit disk as its point spectrum. There’s nothing wrong with this. What you might be thinking is the fact that, given a self-adjoint (or more generally, normal) operator on a separable Hilbert space (so most Hamiltonians in physics, say), its point spectrum must be countable and thus not “continuous”. But this does not apply to non-normal operators, such as the annihilation operator (or $S$ in my example).

Creation and annihilation operators are also not self-adjoint which is another complication m. By contrast, the number operator $a^\dagger a$ is self-adjoint and has the usual discrete number states.

@DavidGao Thank you for your example of the left shift operator! Can you also comment on the spectrum of the creation operator? I have a feeling that it only has a residual spectrum since it does not possess any eigenfunction or the like.

@Godfly666 I believe so. $\text{range}(a^\dagger - \lambda I)^\perp = \text{ker}(a - \bar{\lambda} I)$ is always nontrivial as $\mathbb{C}$ is the point spectrum of $a$, so $a^\dagger - \lambda I$ always has range that is not dense, which means $\mathbb{C}$ is the residual spectrum of $a^\dagger$.

I think both @whpowell96 and @DavidGao are correct. $a$ is neither normal, nor bounded, (unless some very specific cases, but if you have $|\alpha\rangle$ for all $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$. I'm sure you are not in one of them, that looks like QFT or molecular physics, not a nice two-level system).
It is quite common for QM operators to not be bounded, and there is no contradiction there, rest assured. If you want to do QM rigorously, you need to contruct explicitely your Hilbert space, and only then, check for boundedness of operators.
Note that it is also quite common in physics to embed the Physical Hilbert space into a much bigger one, for computationnal simplicity, so also be on the lookout for that. (For instance, it is common to use $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ in basic QM, but to use distributions as well, like $\delta(x)\notin L^2$,so make sure you check boundedness with respect to the correct space.)

For a very rigorous treatment of the quantum harmonic oscillator using rigged Hilbert spaces is available in Quantum Mechanics in Rigged Hilbert Space Language by de Madrid, which is available for free online.
